# ODBC connection to Moodle database on Ubuntu AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mariadb, ubuntu-server

I need to access to Moodle database, which is running in Ubuntu Server located in AWS, via ODBC on Windows. The database is MariaDB and I installed the appropriate driver in Windows, along with the ip, port, user and password but it fails with the message:
'Connection failed [HY000] [ma-3.1.17] Can't connect to server'
I don't know if I to configure anything in AWS, besides opening 3306 port, on Ubuntu, on MariaDB...?

Comment: Were you able to do telnet on port 3306 ?

Comment: Could you provide the syntax please?

Comment: Telnet isn't installed by default in modern versions of Windows but you do the same test by opening powershell and running this command: `New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("0.0.0.0", 3306)` with your IP address instead of `0.0.0.0` and change the port if required.  If your port is open and listening you will see "Connected : True" in the output.

Comment: The port is not opened, I have tried telnet and putty, there must be something else to activate in aws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with several steps, but I think that the decisive was the last one:

```
* Change localhost to 0.0.0.0 in bind-address
sudo vi /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
sudo systemctl restart mariadb.service
sudo systemctl status mariadb.service

* Install netstat
sudo apt update
sudo apt install net-tools
sudo netstat -tulnp | grep mariadb

* Allow firewall
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
mysql -u root -h YOUR_IP -p

* Open UFW
sudo ufw allow 3306/tcp

* Create new user for odbc
CREATE USER 'YOUR-USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR-PASSWORD';
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,DROP,INDEX,ALTER ON moodle.* TO 'YOUR-USER'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Thanks you all for your help